# Is this phrase correctly written?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I need to explain the users of my mobile application that if they do a "swipe" movement they will see the other categories of information of their device.

Please, can you tell me if this phrase is correctly written or has some failures?

Thank you

> Swipe horizontally right or left to see the different information
>   categories of your device. Press upper left corner menu button to see
>   the App sections

This is what swipe means:

[image]

Comment: How do you swipe horizontally if it's not left or right? I would go for _swipe horizontally_ **or** _swipe right or left_, but I wouldn't combine them. Also, press_the_ menu button.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. While you already found your answer I urge you to visit the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out about good questions in case you want to use this site further. Be advised that in general proofreading is off-topic unless your own reason for doubting the sentence is clearly specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

> Swipe left or right to see different categories of your device. Tap the upper left button to see the app sections.

Without more context, it's hard to provide more feedback. But this is a start. If you specify left or right, you don't have to say horizontally. "Tap" is the preferred term for touch apps. Upper left already means corner and the button is assumed to be a menu navigation I assume.

Comment: Thank you. It is fine to say "information categories" instead of "categories"? the app is about information and it is spread into categories

Comment: Not sure what you mean without seeing the app. But go with whatever you think is right.